# QGIS Server | WMS | Filter with LIKE operator and % wildcard

Tags: wms, filter, qgis-server

QGIS Server is accepting with WMS serving the filter operator `LIKE` (and also `ILIKE` in non geopackage bases). In order to use `LIKE` reasonably also the wildcard `"%"` should be usable:

```
...&FILTER=myLayer: "field1" LIKE 'myStreet%'

or

...&FILTER=myLayer: "field1" LIKE '%myStreet%'
```

Unfortunately the wildcard character `%` is refused by QGIS Server with the message:

> The filter string %22field1%22%20LIKE%20%27myStreet%%27 has
> been rejected because of security reasons. Note: Text strings have to
> be enclosed in single or double quotes. A space between each word /
> special character is mandatory. Allowed Keywords and special
> characters are
> IS,NOT,NULL,AND,OR,IN,=,<,>=,>,>=,!=,',',(,),DMETAPHONE,SOUNDEX. Not
> allowed are semicolons in the filter expression.

Is there any workaround in order to use the `LIKE` operator together with wildcards in a QGIS Server WMS context?

Comment: Have you tried encoding it as an OGC filter? I think that is required by the WMS standard so it should work

Comment: According to the QGIS Server documentation, OGC filter encoding (XML) is only supported for WFS and not WMS. OGC filter encoding XML/KVP for WMS is still in the state of a feature request.

Comment: In the meantime I found that if the wildcard character % is encoded as %25 before normal URL encoding is done, the wildcard is accepted by the QGIS Server WMS service and returns the results as expected: "&FILTER=myLayer: "field1" LIKE '%25myStreet%25'